# How to avoid ElementClickInterceptedException when working with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, exception, click

I use `selenium` with `python` and want to mark a checkbox by clicking on it.
After having identified the `<input>` tag of the checkbox with selenium, I attempt to click on it with

```
checkbox.click()
```

However, it throws the `ElementClickInterceptedException`.

I identify the checkbox I want to click on through a loop. When I try to click on the checkbox outside of the loop (by manually running the code after it was identified and saved to a variable), I found two things:

- All things equal, I still get the exception
- When I click in the browser window once (that was opened with selenium) and then run `checkbox.click()`, it works as expected

Any ideas why and how I could attempt to slove this issue (i.e. being able to click on the checkbox within the loop)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either deal with the overlapping element or use javascript

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkbox)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the checkbox is not directly interactable. You may have to click on the label/text next to the checkbox.

or May be you have to wait till the element is clickable since your are running in a loop.